# In a multi-monitor setup, how do I pin my windows?

Tags: google-chrome, multiple-monitors

I have a 3-monitor setup. When the machine starts I want to have 3 Chrome windows, one on each monitor, each pointing to a different URL. The system has a Nvidia Quattro graphics card.

How can I "pin" or setup the windows on startup?

Comment: Any particular OS?

Comment: Windows 7 32 bit

Answer (score 1):

Apparently these switches should work, but I didn't have any luck with them. Perhaps you will do better:

```
--window-position=x,y
--window-size=w,h
```

Source: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

If you do get them working you just need to set up three Chrome shortcuts that do what you want and drop them into your startup folder in the start menu.